# Change the origin and destination icon of the generated route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that generates a route with an origin, a destination and a series of waypoints. What I want to try to do is change the icon of the point of origin and destination.

In my case, the origin and destination are the same, since the idea is that the route is part of a product distribution logistics that starts and returns to the same place.

I have tried placing the parameter "suppressMarkers: true" in the DirectionsRendered settings, but from what I understand, the icon I place will affect all the route markers, both the origin, the destination and the waypoints. All I need is to change the origin and destination.

One thing that occurred to me is that the start and end point are markers, but apparently a marker object cannot be placed in the DirectionsService () settings.

**EDIT**

I added in the example code the parameter "suppressMarkers: true" and then, when running service.route and the status === "OK" I get var `leg = response.routes [0] .legs [0];` to get the start and end coordinates, and then I add a custom marker. The problem is that they are not added

Does anyone know how to do it?

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -32.949798,
      lng: -60.681911
    }
  });

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('right-panel'),
    suppressMarkers: true
  });

  directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsRenderer.getDirections());
  });
  var start = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.949798, -60.681911);
  var end = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.949798, -60.681911);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addWaypoint(event.latLng);
    displayRoute(start, end, directionsService, directionsRenderer);
  });

  displayRoute(start, end, directionsService, directionsRenderer);
}

function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
  var waypoints = [{
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(-32.930572, -60.662137)
    },
    {
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(-32.923554, -60.665930)
    },
    {
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(-32.936270, -60.652841)
    },
  ];
  for (var i=0; i<addedWaypoints.length;i++) {
    waypoints.push({
      location: addedWaypoints[i]
    });
  }
  service.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    waypoints: waypoints,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    avoidTolls: true,
    avoidHighways: true
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      display.setDirections(response);
      
      var leg = response.routes[ 0 ].legs[ 0 ];
      console.log(leg.start_location)
      makeMarker( leg.start_location, icons.start, 'title');
      makeMarker( leg.end_location, icons.end, 'title');
      
    } else {
      alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
var addedWaypoints = [];

var icons = {start: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
     // URL
     'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png',
     // (width,height)
     new google.maps.Size( 44, 32 ),
     // The origin point (x,y)
     new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
     // The anchor point (x,y)
     new google.maps.Point( 22, 32 )
    ),
    end: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
     // URL
     'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png',
     // (width,height)
     new google.maps.Size( 44, 32 ),
     // The origin point (x,y)
     new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
     // The anchor point (x,y)
     new google.maps.Point( 22, 32 )
    )
};

function makeMarker(position, icon, title) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
     position: position,
     map: map,
     icon: icon,
     title: title
    });
}

function addWaypoint(latLng) {
  addedWaypoints.push(latLng);
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var totalDistance = 0;
  var totalDuration = 0;
  var minutes = 0;
  var hours = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    totalDistance += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    totalDuration += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
  }
  totalDistance = totalDistance / 1000;

  var hours = Math.floor(totalDuration / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((totalDuration % 3600) / 60);
  var seconds = totalDuration % 60;

  hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  if (hours == 0) {
    var result = minutes + " min";
  } else {
    var result = hours + ':' + minutes + " hs";
  }

  document.getElementById('total_distance').innerHTML = totalDistance.toFixed(2) + ' km ';
  document.getElementById('total_duration').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```css
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select,
#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 63%;
  height: 100%;
}

#right-panel {
  float: right;
  width: 34%;
  height: 100%;
}

.panel {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMZqunCMWco2noEHk5BlWyJExOPn1XCRU&callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
  <p>Distance: <span id="total_distance"></span></p>
  <p>Duration: <span id="total_duration"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The only way to change the markers (and make them unique), is to use `suppressMarkers: true`, then render the markers yourself.

Comment: @geocodezip I have modified the example, trying to add a custom marker to the point of origin and destination, after status === "OK", but it does not work. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? If you know what I am doing wrong, give me an answer so I can mark it as correct :)